# get sourcecode after javascript execution with curl

Tags: javascript, html, curl

Is it possible to get the html source code of a webpage with curl and the run a javascript interpreter over it, so i get the generated content?

The Page i need to get uses some encoded and genereated content in there so i want to first run the javascript to get the escaped and generated content... or do i need to regex the javascript and "compile" the javascript on my own? Like

```
curl <myurl> | perl -ne 'm/unescape\((.*)\)/; print "$1"' | <now to something with that>
```

i known there is no javascript engine in curl but can i just call another script / programm to do the job?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28506533/3063226

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it, but it's more involved than I think you realize.  Neither `curl` nor `wget` have Javascript engines, so you'll need something that has one.

I would start by looking at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and/or [Chromium Headless](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md).

Comment: nice, i didnt knew that there where such things :) I will also update my screenshot script which currently goes over some edges then using phantomjs!

Comment: PhantomJS has been suspended as of March 2018. I'd love to know of a more up-to-date option. Depending on the use, there might be security issues with using an unmaintained package.