# How to simulate a cURL request with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, shell, curl

Currently, I'm checking a site with `curl` and `grep` for a particular pattern.

```
for i in {1..300}; do
  curl -s http://example.com | grep "Welcome to " 
  status=$? 
  # if status is 0 - print found else not found
  sleep 1;
done
```

How to convert this shell code into JavaScript code?  I would like to print something like this:

```
//cURL req & get status of grep
if ( status == 0 )
  alert("Its found");
else
  alert("Not found Yet");
```

Thanks for any help or JSFiddle references. :)

---

**EDIT:**  I came across this http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/ and this [get sourcecode after javascript execution with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514604/get-sourcecode-after-javascript-execution-with-curl)  I'm hoping for something like that based on JavaScript.

**EDIT 2:** Running on browser, need to verify this from browser. Platform already uses jQuery (Flask-based server).

Comment: Use AJAX. But browsers normally can't perform AJAX to other domains.

Comment: You can allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com/ to perform AJAX to other domains.

Comment: You need to include more details if you are running on a browser or node.js

Comment: thanks for the responses. pls see my new edit.

Comment: What platform? Browser? -- Not many options for the browser without using a proxy (send ajax request to server, server curl's target server, sends resposne back to browser)