# Get the content (text) of an URL after Javascript has run with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, http-headers

Is it possible to get the content of a URL with PHP (using some sort of function like `file_get_contents` or `header`) but only after the execution of some JavaScript code?

Example:

mysite.com has a script that does `loadUrlAfterJavascriptExec('http://exampletogetcontent.com/')` and prints/echoes the content. imagine that some jQuery runs on `http://exampletogetcontent.com/` that changes DOM, and `loadUrlAfterJavascriptExec` will get the resulting HTML

Can we do that?

Just to be clear, what I want is to get the content of a page through a URL, but only after JavaScript runs on the target page (the one PHP is getting its content).

I am aware PHP runs before the page is sent to the client, and JS only after that, but thought that maybe there was an expert workaround.

Comment: no :-) you want browser to get the page and run all js files for that page and get the page after execution? but you don't have control of that page? then the answer is NO, you can't

Comment: are the requested urls on the same domain?

Comment: @Joelerr actually the are Joelerr

Answer (score 17):

**Update 2** Adds more details on how to use `phantomjs` from PHP.

**Update 1** (after clarification that javascript on **target** page need to run first)

### Method 1:Use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)(will execute javascript);

**1.** Download [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) and place the executable in a path that your PHP binary can reach.

**2.** Place the following 2 files in the same directory:

**get-website.php**

```
<?php
    
    $phantom_script= dirname(__FILE__). '/get-website.js'; 


    $response =  exec ('phantomjs ' . $phantom_script);

    echo  htmlspecialchars($response);
    ?>
```

**get-website.js**

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://google.com/', function(status) {
 console.log(page.content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

**3.** Browse to `get-website.php` and the target site, `http://google.com` contents will return after executing inline javascript. You can also call this from a command line using `php /path/to/get-website.php`.

### Method 2:Use Ajax with PHP (No phantomjs so won't run javascript);

**/get-website.php**

```
<?php
    
    $html=file_get_contents('http://google.com');
    echo $html;
    ?>
```

**test.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>on demo</title>
<style>
p {
color: red;
}
span {
color: blue;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='click_me'>Click me</button>
<span style="display:none;"></span>
<script>

$( "#click_me" ).click(function () {
    $.get("/get-website.php", function(data) {
        var json = {
            html: JSON.stringify(data),
            delay: 1
        };
        alert(json.html);
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @victor-ferreira Did you have a chance to look at this solution?

Comment: This is out of date and PhantomJS is no longer in production.

Answer (score 3):

I found a fantastic page on this, it's an entire tutorial on how to process the DOM of a page in PHP which is entirely created using javascript.

https://www.jacobward.co.uk/using-php-to-scrape-javascript-jquery-json-websites/
"PhantomJS development is suspended until further notice" so that option isn't a good one.

Comment: The article does not seem to be available anymore but it's available on waybackmachine

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest and best way is using this package
https://github.com/spatie/browsershot
just install it completely and use the below code

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->bodyHtml()
```

Answer (score -1):

All the PHP runs before the information is sent to the client.
All the JavaScript runs after the information is sent to the client.

To do something with PHP after the page loads, the page will need to either

1. reload, saving the JavaScript generated info in a cookie or as POST data (not ideal) OR
2. make an Ajax call to another PHP file to get the data. (much better)

Since the data appears to be in different file than your PHP anyway, this is a pretty good solution. Since you tagged it jQuery, I assume you're using it.

[jQuery has a set of pages about how it implements Ajax](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

But the easiest way to use jQuery for this is [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

ex:

```
$.post( "http://example.com/myDataFile.txt", function( data ) {
    //do more JavaScript stuff with the data you just retrieved
});
```

`$.post()`, as the name implies, can send data along with the request for the data file, so if that request is to, say, a PHP file, the PHP file can use that data.

ex:

```
$.post( "http://example.com/myDataFile.txt",
    { foo: "bar"; yabba: "dabba" },
    function( data ) {
       //do more JavaScript stuff with the data you just retrieved
});
```

the data should be in JSON format in key/value pairs.