# Simple HTML DOM and curl: how to get content when website have ajax loaded code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, simple-html-dom

So i've made a few **scrapers** in my past but every **scraper** that i made is taking content from non dynamically loaded page. Basically page that is not using any ajax.

But now i am looking for solutions almost 2 days and can't find any. The page that i am trying to download and use information's from have it's content loaded from ajax. So basically when you go to that page it load content, than table that i need to get is loaded with ajax on page load.

And it looks like curl doesn't understand that page content i need is loaded dynamically so i always get `boolean:false` or `property does not exists` response.

This is the code that i am trying to get.

```
    $requ = require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/simple_html_dom.php' );
    $getfeed = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($getfeed, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($getfeed, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://wizzair.com/');
    curl_setopt($getfeed, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($getfeed, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    $str = curl_exec($getfeed);
    curl_close($getfeed);

    $html = str_get_html($str);

    foreach($html->find('div.fare-finder__calendar__days__day__container') as $key => $value) {
         print_r($value);
    }
```

So is there a way to make it understand that content is loaded with ajax on that page so at least to make curl wait a few seconds before it loads a page ?

Comment: There are a few questions here about this type of thing. Have you seen [this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505501/get-the-content-text-of-an-url-after-javascript-has-run-with-php)

Comment: Maybe something like phantomjscloud is an option for you.

Comment: I see this could be good solution with something like phantomjscloud and i just tried it but it doesn't work specifically with wizzair.com website.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? cURL usually doesn't interpret any JS code after all