# PHP get element from page after the page is fully loaded

Tags: php

I want to take content of `#result` [from this page](http://www.fantasynamegenerators.com/alien-names.php#.WaBXGZOg-9Y),but that div is being loaded after the page is loaded.Now i use this code

```
$url = 'http://www.fantasynamegenerators.com/alien-names.php#.WaBXGZOg-9Y';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div id="result">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
```

To get content of that div,but because that div is getting loaded after the page,it returns the whole page.Now how can i tell php to wait till the page is fully loaded and then take it's content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the content (text) of an URL after Javascript has run with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505501/get-the-content-text-of-an-url-after-javascript-has-run-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can't gets result of this part of page that isn't in source code. This div is fulled with data using code written with JavaScript in `alienNames.js`. By running `file_get_contents()` you are downloading only HTML structure of give page...

Summarizing, You can't execute js script with php.