# Simple HTML DOM scraping after javascript on site complete or executed

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

```
<?php
include_once('libs/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('thewebsite.com');
echo $html->find('.list_tag',0)
```

I'm trying to get the tag of a website but due to a script
it return as "Loading..." Meaning it hasn't load the script that getting the tags and It only return "Loading..", If I visited the site the tags are there but if I disable the javascript of chrome(browser) it output the website as "Loading".

Anyway to parse the data after the script run?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the content (text) of an URL after Javascript has run with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505501/get-the-content-text-of-an-url-after-javascript-has-run-with-php)

Comment: @Nima i have no idea how to put this one into the code? can you please explain, can i use it like include_once('libs/simple_html_dom.php');

Comment: i'll look for phantomjs thanks