# Can't parse specific site with wget

Tags: bots, wget, sites

I'm trying to parse https://app.xdao.app/ site using wget.

I used:

```
wget https://app.xdao.app/
```

and

```
wget -r -p https://app.xdao.app/
```

Always I got the same result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/assets/img/favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>xDAO App</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.e975bc04.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.ab9443f5.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.578c0be9.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Why? I want to get more full htm file, like I got result with yahoo.com for instance. I tried curl and got the same empty htm also.

PS: also when I do save as web page in FF I also get full html.

Here page downloaded with FF:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="https://app.xdao.app/assets/img/favicon.svg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>xDAO App</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin="" src="xDAO%20App_files/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="https://app.xdao.app/assets/vendor.ab9443f5.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="xDAO%20App_files/index.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"> <div class="fixed left-0 right-0 bottom-2 text-center z-50"></div> <div class="flex justify-between p-2 lg:p-4 items-center  w-full"><img src="xDAO%20App_files/logo_full_blue.svg" class="self-start h-10 hidden md:block ml-5 mt-1" alt=""> <img src="xDAO%20App_files/logo_blue.svg" class="h-10 md:hidden" alt=""> <div class="md:flex space-x-4 items-center self-end hidden"> <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#/create"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-plus-circle "><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="16"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line></svg> <p>Create DAO</p></a> <button class="btn btn-primary">Connect Wallet</button></div> <div class="flex space-x-2 items-center self-end md:hidden"> <a class="btn-mobile btn-mobile-ghost" href="#/create"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-plus-circle "><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="16"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line></svg> <p>Create DAO</p></a> <button class="btn-mobile btn-mobile-primary">Connect Wallet</button></div></div> <div class="flex"><aside class="h-screen top-0 sticky"><div class="hidden md:flex md:flex-col md:space-y-2 md:px-5 md:py-12 md:w-64"><a href="#/"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1 chosenbutton"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-home "><path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path><polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">Home</p></div></div></a> <a href="#/ecosystem"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-grid "><rect x="3" y="3" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="14" y="3" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="14" y="14" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="3" y="14" width="7" height="7"></rect></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">Ecosystem</p></div></div></a> <a href="#/mydaos"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-list "><line x1="8" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line><line x1="8" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line><line x1="3" y1="6" x2="3.01" y2="6"></line><line x1="3" y1="12" x2="3.01" y2="12"></line><line x1="3" y1="18" x2="3.01" y2="18"></line></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">My DAOs</p></div></div></a> <a href="#/create"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-plus-circle "><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="16"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">Create</p></div></div></a></div></aside> <main class="flex-1 py-8 px-4 md:py-12 md:px-16 lg:py-9 lg:px-16 w-full"><div class="card"><p class="text-h4 font-semibold">4 Simple Steps to Start</p> <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-4 gap-8 mt-4"><div class="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1"><a href="https://metamask.io/download.html" target="_blank"><img src="xDAO%20App_files/01.svg" alt="" class="w-full"></a></div> <div class="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1"><button class="w-full"><img src="xDAO%20App_files/02.svg" alt="" class="w-full"></button></div> <div class="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1"><button class="w-full"><img src="xDAO%20App_files/03.svg" alt="" class="w-full"></button></div> <div class="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1"><a href="#/create"><img src="xDAO%20App_files/04.svg" alt="" class="w-full"></a></div></div> <a href="https://docs.xdao.app/manual/how-to-start" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-ghost w-full h-7.5 mt-12"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18px" height="18px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-book "><path d="M4 19.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 17H20"></path><path d="M6.5 2H20v20H6.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4 19.5v-15A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 2z"></path></svg> <p>Guide</p></button></a></div> <div class="card mt-2"><div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8"><div class="col-span-2 lg:col-span-1"><p class="text-h6 font-medium">About xDAO Project</p> <p class="text-body text-grey mt-1">xDAO is a DeFi protocol for quick and easy creation of Decentralized
        Autonomous Organizations — DAOs. Combine your crypto assets to manage
        them in more efficient and secure way by using auto-generated smart
        contracts. A clear voting system allows you to make collective decisions
        and be confident in their exact execution.</p></div> <div class="col-span-2 lg:col-span-1 space-y-2"><div class="flex space-x-2 items-center text-primary"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22px" height="22px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-shield "><path d="M12 22s8-4 8-10V5l-8-3-8 3v7c0 6 8 10 8 10z"></path></svg> <a href="https://github.com/pessimistic-io/audits/blob/main/xDao%20Security%20Analysis%20by%20Pessimistic.pdf" class="font-medium underline" target="_blank">Audit</a></div> <div class="flex space-x-2 items-center text-primary"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22px" height="22px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-code "><polyline points="16 18 22 12 16 6"></polyline><polyline points="8 6 2 12 8 18"></polyline></svg> <a href="https://github.com/xDAO-App/xdaocontracts" target="_blank" class="font-medium underline">Source Code</a></div> <div class="flex space-x-2 items-center text-primary"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22px" height="22px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-link "><path d="M10 13a5 5 0 0 0 7.54.54l3-3a5 5 0 0 0-7.07-7.07l-1.72 1.71"></path><path d="M14 11a5 5 0 0 0-7.54-.54l-3 3a5 5 0 0 0 7.07 7.07l1.71-1.71"></path></svg> <a href="https://xdao.app/" class="font-medium underline" target="_blank">Official Website</a></div> <div class="flex space-x-2 items-center text-primary"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22px" height="22px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-book "><path d="M4 19.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 17H20"></path><path d="M6.5 2H20v20H6.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4 19.5v-15A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 2z"></path></svg> <a href="https://docs.xdao.app/" target="_blank" class="font-medium underline">Docs</a></div></div></div></div></main></div> <div class="bg-darkactive fixed bottom-0 w-full md:hidden grid grid-cols-4 gap-2 z-50 p-2"><div class="col-span-1"><a href="#/"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1 chosenbutton"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-home "><path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path><polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">Home</p></div></div></a></div> <div class="col-span-1"><a href="#/ecosystem"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-grid "><rect x="3" y="3" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="14" y="3" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="14" y="14" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="3" y="14" width="7" height="7"></rect></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">Ecosystem</p></div></div></a></div> <div class="col-span-1"><a href="#/mydaos"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-list "><line x1="8" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line><line x1="8" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line><line x1="3" y1="6" x2="3.01" y2="6"></line><line x1="3" y1="12" x2="3.01" y2="12"></line><line x1="3" y1="18" x2="3.01" y2="18"></line></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">My DAOs</p></div></div></a></div> <div class="col-span-1"><a href="#/create"><div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center space-y-2 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 px-3 py-3 md:py-4 md:px-5 rounded-xl text-grey transition duration-200 hover:bg-hovergrey hover:text-primary svelte-1i2lpd1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-plus-circle "><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="16"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="16" y2="12"></line></svg> <div class="text-captionsm md:text-title font-semibold"><p slot="text">Create</p></div></div></a></div></div> <footer class="p-4 text-center text-grey "><p><a class="hover:underline" href="#/termsandconditions">Terms and Conditions</a>
    |

    <a class="hover:underline" href="#/privacypolicy">Privacy Policy</a> |

    <a class="hover:underline" href="#/amlpolicy">AML Policy</a> <br> <br> <a class="font-medium text-primary hover:underline" target="_blank" href="https://www.tis.bizfile.gov.sg/ngbtisinternet/faces/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/pages/TransactionMain.jspx?authNo=X21255309Q&amp;selectedETransId=prdAuth&amp;uen=202112101H">XGROUP GLOBAL PTE. LTD. Singapore</a> <span class="font-medium">| Powered by Binance Smart Chain</span></p></footer> <div class="h-24 md:hidden"></div></div>
   
</body></html>'
```

Thanks for any advices

Answer (score 1):

This

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.e975bc04.js"></script>
```

is `<script>` tag, when your browser encounter that it does execute JavaScript instruction in file pointed by `src`. In this case it apparently fill page with content, thus you might get *full html* via Firefox. So far I know executing JavaScript is out of scope of `wget`. You would need tool which is able to execute JavaScript, not only download resource.

Comment: Thank you. Please check the file that I downloaded with FF (I added them in my post).
As you can see there is nested tag <div id="app">, but in code downloaded with wget only root one. Why? I don't need in js. All info in index is sufficient. But how can I get it correctly?

Comment: @vns955 : Daweo is correct. <div id="app"></div> is filled with content by the Javascript. I already tested, but you may test it for yourself: deactivate JS in browser and access the page - you'll find the element empty. Related SO answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505501/get-the-content-text-of-an-url-after-javascript-has-run-with-php). Related resource: [link](https://www.webscrapingapi.com/php-web-scraping/)